# docker cannot access intranet that host can

Tags: docker, npm, proxy, npm-registry

I am behind a corporate proxy. I have `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and `NO_PROXY` set in the image. When I'm connected to the network I have access to a private `npm` registry that is on this intranet. My docker image is unable to access this registry.

On the host machine, a mac, I can run:

```
curl https://<registry>/nodejs/content/groups/npm/lodash
```

And I get the JSON for the package.

On the docker image I run the same command and I get this:

```
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

When I `npm install` with the registry set it also returns the same issue.

Why can't docker access the same endpoint that my host machine can? How can I enable it to?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the host's network. If you are able to access that URL from your local, then it should work. You just need to add the **--network host** argument to your build/run command.

Example:

```
$ docker build <all the other args> --network host .
$ docker run <all the other args> --network host .
```

Docker creates a bridge network by default but you can force it to use your local network with --network host arg.

Comment: why can I not use -p when I add --network host. It returns no error, but -p is ignored

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, which was there is a docker network created by some compose file remains there

```
docker network ls
```

I removed the danging one and retain the intranet access

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but it migh thelp someone. I had the same problem and my solution was configure docker daemon to use my intranet DNS

Edit the `daemon.json` file

```
sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

The file should look something like this

```
{
  "dns": ["ip-here", "ip-here"]
}
```

Restart de daemon

```
sudo service docker restart
```